# trying to use lucene search with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, solr, lucene

I am trying to learn about lucene to build a robust search mechanism for mean stack application

But i have understood the conceptual part Apache Solr from these series of videos
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zh_aYQkG0Wc&index=3&list=PLJbE6j2EG1pZ7YfU05bCqdv5bDkKo75nQ

but not sure how start implement it

As most of the source i have refereed use java and i have few confusions like

*what is lucene and solr ie they both mean the same
*if want to build a search mechanism how should i use them 
*Do we have a npm module which will help in performing the search

can anybody please refer some source which will help to do search for mongodb nodejs and lucene stack are how to build a module (mechanism) which will help do to perform search on mongodb collections

Comment: Lucene is the library / specification, Solr is built on top of Lucene (by introducing an HTTP interface to Lucene's capabilities and adding its own features). There's javascript libraries available for talking to Solr, but the interface is standard HTTP so you can make it work with any HTTP client. [The Apache Solr Reference Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Apache+Solr+Reference+Guide)

Answer (score 0):

> what is lucene and solr ie they both mean the same

Lucene is a search library built in Java. Solr is a web application built on top of Lucene. Simply Solr = Lucene + Added features.

Lucene:

Apache Lucene is a high-performance, full-featured text search engine library written entirely in Java. It is a technology suitable for nearly any application that requires full-text search.

Solr:

Solr major features include powerful full-text search, hit highlighting, faceted search, dynamic clustering, database integration, and rich document (e.g., Word, PDF) handling. Solr is highly scalable, providing distributed search and index replication, and it powers the search and navigation features of many of the world's largest internet sites. This site is powered by Solr.
Solr uses the Lucene Java search library at its core for full-text indexing and search, and has REST-like HTTP/XML and JSON APIs.

> Mongo and Lucene

https://github.com/rstiller/mongo-lucene

https://www.jayway.com/2010/11/14/full-text-search-with-mongodb-and-lucene-analyzers/

> Mongo and Solr

[solr Data Import Handlers for MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345335/solr-data-import-handlers-for-mongodb)

[How to import and index mongodb data in solr 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349859/how-to-import-and-index-mongodb-data-in-solr-4)

[What would be the motivation to integrate mongodb with solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291826/what-would-be-the-motivation-to-integrate-mongodb-with-solr)

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29127828146/introducing-mongo-connector

https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector

Hope it Helps!